# Testcontainers fail with Docker must be present in order for testcontainers to work properly on GKE with containerd nodes

Tags: docker, jenkins, testcontainers, containerd, jenkins-kubernetes

I'm preparing our GKE clusters for a future update to Kubernetes 1.24. This version removes dockershim support so the new container runtime to use is containerd. Thus, I've generated a new containerd based node pool.

Our Jenkins server is running on Kubernetes, and is using the [kubernetes plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/kubernetes/) to provision dynamic agents as pods.

The agent configuration included a host path volume to provide access to Docker:

[image]

After switching to containerd workers, testcontainers doesn't work anymore, throwing the folloging exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
  
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean 
with name 'dockerPresenceMarker' defined in class path resource 
[com/playtika/test/common/spring/DockerPresenceBootstrapConfiguration.class]: 
Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
Failed to instantiate [com.playtika.test.common.spring.DockerPresenceMarker]: 
Factory method 'dockerPresenceMarker' threw exception; nested exception is 
com.playtika.test.common.spring.DockerNotPresentException: Docker must be present 
in order for testcontainers to work properly!
```

What should I do to allow testcontainers to work with containerd on Jenkins agents?

Comment: Hey, this code does not come from https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java but from https://github.com/Playtika/testcontainers-spring-boot (?). I would suggest integrating against `testcontainers-java` directly.